# Edited Post | How to run TestNG tests from main(), I have written the main class - But what now?

Tags: java, xml, selenium, frameworks, testng

I am trying to run my XML using a 'Main' class, with a template I have found. 
How to I proceed from here?

Do I need to use:

> 'Export' -> '.Jar'

And then run the main class?
Need tips I a bit lost

```
package TestMain;

import java.util.List;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.testng.xml.Parser;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class MainOfAllMains {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();

    String xmlFileName = "runXML.xml";
    List <XmlSuite> suite1;  
    try
    {
        suite = (XmlSuite)(new Parser(xmlFileName).parse());  **//
        testng.setXmlSuites((List<XmlSuite>) suite);  
        testng.run(); 
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}
}

Comment: Hint: its `java.util.List`, not `java.awt.List`. 3&4: Just that, you never declare a variable `testng` - its `suite`

Comment: I have made this change, No errors appear. Please see the edited post of how to proceed from here

Comment: Try to `Export -> Runnable jar file` and the run file by double click or from the command line `java -jar MyJarFile.jar`

Answer (score 0):

At the place of

```
import java.awt.List;
```

Use

```
import java.util.List;
```

This will resolve your first problem.

Comment: I have made this change, No errors appear. Please see the edited post of how to proceed from here